# mysql update, computer says it works but no change in database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
<?php 

  require('dbconnect.php');

  $indexno = $_POST['indexno'];
  $cevap = $_POST['cevap'];
  $cevapdate = gmdate("Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z");
  $query = "UPDATE soru 
               SET cevap = '$cevap', 
                   cevapdate = '$cevapdate' 
             WHERE `index` = '$indexno'";

$link = mysql_query($query);
if(!$link) {
  die('not worked: ' . mysql_error());
} else {
  mysql_close($con);    
  echo 'worked';
}

?>
```

Outcome of this php code is "Worked." but there is no change in the database. The thing is Im trying to update the cevap and cevapdate fields on a row by index id.

Comment: There should be no quotes for `index`. Try removing it

Comment: The field names shouldn't be wrapped in quotes. Try removing them around the "index" field in the `WHERE` statement. **Note: For safety reasons, you should use `mysql_real_escape_string` when using user input in SQL queries.**

Comment: You also can use `mysql_affected_rows` to see if it actually did anything. Your test is just to see if it threw an error.

Comment: @Francois Deschenes: The OP knows - see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6588135/mysql-error-about-updating-table

Comment: I tried removing quotes from index but, It did not work that way. It gave my mysql error. This code doesnt give a error but I cant see adifference my database, something weird?!

Comment: Make sure the criteria filtered by the where clause actually match some of the rows. Try "SELECT * FROM soru WHERE 'index' = '$indexno'"

Comment: He needs the ` around index because index is a keyword.

Comment: @Amir Raminfar solved the problem, thank you.

Comment: Failing to update rows because your WHERE clause didn't allow anything to match is NOT an error condition, so your `if (!$link)` is not a valid way to check for success. That would only work properly if your query had a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the single quotes from aroud the `index`. You should not put single quotes around a column name while writing a query. Write your query this way -

```
$query = "UPDATE soru SET cevap = '$cevap', cevapdate = '$cevapdate' WHERE index = '$indexno'";
```

Comment: its not working that way, I tried that way, it gave me a mysql error. This code doesnt give a error but I cant see a change in my database.

Comment: Actually, it'dbe helpful if you post the error you get when running this query, cos, quotes should not be used for the `index` field in the table

Comment: @user552828: What does the error say? Also, try printing the values of the `$_POST['indexno']` and `$_POST['cevap']`.

Comment: I printed they are correct. when I remove quotes it says You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'index = '2'' at line 1

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape your rows/table with backticks, not single-quotes.

```
$query = "UPDATE `soru`
  SET `cevap` = '$cevap', `cevapdate` = '$cevapdate'
  WHERE `index` = '$indexno'";
```

Also, you should escape your user input to prevent [SQL injections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: They both are still the same.

Comment: You must be making a mistake somewhere else - perhaps you're editing the wrong file or similiar. If the code you paste above is correct, that _should_ have given you an error. Nonetheless, it should work now as well. Are you sure there are any entries in your database where `index` = '$indexno. Perhaps `$indexno` doesn't contain what you think it does.

Comment: You don't _have_ to use backticks.

Comment: @Dark Slipstream: Normally you don't, but `index` is a reserved keyword, so here you do. Under any circumstances, using ' as he did before won't work.